# How to read an API correctly with JSON and create list? In Python

Tags: python, json, api

In Python3 I made a program to read an API (from Brazilian Chamber of Deputies) and get the data in JSON

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados'
```

First I made a list with dictionaries - they are the names of the deputies and the respective API link of each. The parameters were json, number of items per page and page number (there are more than 500 deputies, then there are six pages)

```
deputados = []
for pagina in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
    parametros = {'formato': 'json', 'itens': 100, 'pagina': pagina}
    resposta = requests.get(url, parametros)
    for deputado in resposta.json()['dados']:
        dicionario = {"deputado": deputado['nome'], "link_api": deputado['uri']}
        deputados.append(dicionario)
```

Content of the list:

```
deputados
[{'deputado': 'ABEL MESQUITA JR.',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178957'},
 {'deputado': 'ADAIL CARNEIRO',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178864'},
 {'deputado': 'ADALBERTO CAVALCANTI',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178914'},
 {'deputado': 'ADELMO CARNEIRO LEÃO',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890'},
 {'deputado': 'ADELSON BARRETO',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178968'},
 {'deputado': 'ADEMIR CAMILO',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/133374'},
...
```

I create a dataframe with the result

```
df = pd.DataFrame(deputados)
df.reset_index().head()
index   deputado    link_api
0   0   ABEL MESQUITA JR.   https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...
1   1   ADAIL CARNEIRO  https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...
2   2   ADALBERTO CAVALCANTI    https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...
3   3   ADELMO CARNEIRO LEÃO    https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...
4   4   ADELSON BARRETO     https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...
```

Then I created another list with dictionaries. This time I want to go on every deputy API page and extract some of the data. I put some prints to check the results ("resposta" and "linha"). Parameter now is just json

```
perfis = []
for num, row in df.iterrows():
    parametros = {'formato': 'json'}
    resposta = requests.get(row['link_api'], parametros)
    print(resposta)
    for linha in resposta.json()['dados']:
        print(linha)
        item1 = linha['uri']
        item2 = linha['nomeCivil']
    for linha2 in resposta.json()['ultimoStatus']:
        item3 = linha2['nomeEleitoral']
        item4 = linha2['siglaPartido']
        item5 = linha2['siglaUf']
        item6 = linha2['urlFoto']
    for linha3 in resposta.json()['ultimoStatus/gabinete']:
        item7 = linha3['telefone']
        item8 = linha3['email']
        item9 = linha3['sexo']
        item10 = linha3['dataNascimento']
    dicionario = {"link_api": item1, "nome_completo": item2, "nome_eleitoral": item3, "partido": item4, "uf": item5, "link_foto": item6, "telefone": item7, "e_mail": item8, "sexo": item9, "data_nascimento": item2}    
    perfis.append(dicionario)
```

Here I had an error (string indices must be integers) and the prints showed that the deputy API was not read correctly

```
<Response [200]>
id

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-bfada3632dc2> in <module>()
      6     for linha in resposta.json()['dados']:
      7         print(linha)
----> 8         item1 = linha['uri']
      9         item2 = linha['nomeCivil']
     10     for linha2 in resposta.json()['ultimoStatus']:

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Just confirming, the "resposta" print was = Response [200] and the "linha" = id. 
In the "resposta" case should have the requests.get value of the API link. And "linha" is the json value of the chosen item

Then I individually tested an API link and it worked:

```
resposta = requests.get('https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890')
print(resposta.json())
{'dados': {'id': 178890, 'uri': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890', 'nomeCivil': 'ADELMO CARNEIRO LEAO', 'ultimoStatus': {'id': 178890, 'uri': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890', 'nome': 'ADELMO CARNEIRO LEÃO', 'siglaPartido': 'PT', 'uriPartido': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/36844', 'siglaUf': 'MG', 'idLegislatura': 55, 'urlFoto': 'http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/178890.jpg', 'data': '2015-03-06', 'nomeEleitoral': 'ADELMO CARNEIRO LEÃO', 'gabinete': {'nome': '231', 'predio': '4', 'sala': '231', 'andar': '2', 'telefone': '3215-5231', 'email': 'dep.adelmocarneiroleao@camara.leg.br'}, 'situacao': 'Exercício', 'condicaoEleitoral': 'Suplente', 'descricaoStatus': None}, 'cpf': '', 'sexo': 'M', 'urlWebsite': None, 'redeSocial': [], 'dataNascimento': '1949-05-25', 'dataFalecimento': None, 'ufNascimento': 'MG', 'municipioNascimento': 'Itapagipe', 'escolaridade': 'Doutorado'}, 'links': [{'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890'}]}
```

​The JSON page can be seen here: https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890?formato=json

Please can this mean that some parameter is missing when I try to create the second list?

Comment: `resposta.json()['dados']` is obviously a dictionary so when you iterate over it with a `for..in` loop you're essentially getting its keys, not its values. Add `.values()` at the end to iterate over the values.

Comment: Maybe not all of the api links provide `uri`?

Comment: Hello, thanks. I've put -> for linha in resposta.json () ['data']. values ():

Comment: but the "resposta" print continues Response [200]. and the "linha" print shows 178957, which is the id value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this line:

```
for linha in resposta.json()['dados']:
```

Here is an example of what you have in `resposta.json()['dados']`:

```
{'ufNascimento': 'MG', 'municipioNascimento': 'Teófilo Otoni', 'redeSocial': [], 'id': 133374, 'dataNascimento': '1964-05-30', 'dataFalecimento': None, 'urlWebsite': None, 'ultimoStatus': {'siglaPartido': 'PODE', 'condicaoEleitoral': 'Suplente', 'idLegislatura': 55, 'nome': 'ADEMIR CAMILO', 'id': 133374, 'nomeEleitoral': 'ADEMIR CAMILO', 'descricaoStatus': None, 'uri': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/133374', 'uriPartido': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/36896', 'situacao': 'Exercício', 'urlFoto': 'http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/133374.jpg', 'gabinete': {'predio': '4', 'nome': '556', 'andar': '5', 'sala': '556', 'telefone': '3215-5556', 'email': 'dep.ademircamilo@camara.leg.br'}, 'siglaUf': 'MG', 'data': '2016-04-19'}, 'nomeCivil': 'ADEMIR CAMILO PRATES RODRIGUES', 'cpf': '', 'escolaridade': None, 'sexo': 'M', 'uri': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/133374'}
```

It's a dictionary.

`for x in dictonary` loops in `dictionary`'s **keys**, so you are looping on a list:

```
['urlWebsite', 'sexo', 'nomeCivil', 'cpf', 'ultimoStatus', 'dataFalecimento', 'municipioNascimento', 'uri', 'id', 'escolaridade', 'dataNascimento', 'redeSocial', 'ufNascimento']
```

So, writing `item1 = linha['uri']` it's like writing `item1 = ['foo', 'bar']['baz']` which obviously does not means anything.

Quick fix: replace `for linha in resposta.json()['dados']:` by `linha = resposta.json()['dados']` and unindent following code. It would works

Comment: Thank you very much. The command (linha = resposta.json()['dados']) worked fine. But when I try to get the dictionary inside 'dados' it does not work (linha2 = resposta.json()['dados/ultimoStatus']). It has this error: KeyError: KeyError: 'dados/ultimoStatus'

Comment: In order to access one dictionary within another, should the command be another?

Comment: You cannot do `a_dict['foo/bar']` to access key `foo` > `bar`. What you want is `linha2 = resposta.json()['dados']['ultimoStatus']`